# Probability of Finding a Particle in the Ground-state after the Size of the Box is Doubled

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

A particle of mass $m$ is contained in a one-dimensional infinite well extending from $x=-{L\over2}$ to $x=+{L\over2}$. The particle is in its ground state given by 
$$|{\psi_0(x)}\rangle=\sqrt{2\over{L}}\cos(\frac{\pi x}{L})$$
 The walls of the box are moved suddenly to form a box extending from $x=-L$ to $x=+L$. What is the probability that the particle will be in the ground state?

My solution

Using the *sudden expansion approximation* the initial state of the particle in the box of length $L$ will not have enough time to respond to the expansion and so the eigenstate of the particle after the change is completed is $$|{\psi_n} (x)\rangle=\sqrt\frac{2}{L}\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L}); x{\epsilon}[-{L\over2},{L\over2}]$$
$$|{\psi_n(x)}\rangle=0;   x{\epsilon}[-L,L]$$
The eigenstate for a particle of mass $m$ in a one-dimensional box extending form $x=-L$ to $x=+L$ is
$$|{\phi_n(x)}\rangle=\sqrt\frac{1}{L}\cos(\frac{{\pi}x}{2L})$$ for odd $n$
and 
$$|{\phi_n(x)}\rangle=\sqrt\frac{1}{L}\sin(\frac{{\pi}x}{2L})$$ for even $n$

The probability of finding that the particle will be in the ground-state is 
$$P= \int_{-{L\over2}}^{L\over2}(\langle{\phi_1(x)}|{\psi_1(x)}\rangle)^2 dx$$
 Which comes out to be 
$$P=\left(8\over{3{\pi}}\right)^2$$
My question is why when calculating the probability the limit of integration is from $x={-{L\over2}}$ to $x={L\over2}$ and not from $x=-L$ to $x=+L$? Does the question mean by ”The probability of finding that the particle will be in the ground-state” - the probability of finding the particle in the ground-state of the new box?

And secondly do I need to use the argument that the eigenvalues of both the hamiltonians will be the same?

Comment: not sure what your second question is asking, but I also think you should integrate from -L to L.

Comment: If I use the argument that the eigenvalues of the two hamiltonians are the same, say in the first case $$E_n=\frac{n^2{\pi^2}{\hbar^2}}{2mL^2}$$
and the second case $$E'_n=\frac{n'^2{\pi^2}{\hbar^2}}{2m(2L)^2}$$ then $$n'=2n$$ and the probability becomes 0.5.

Comment: Because outside of +-L/2 the integrand is zero anyway, so it doesn't matter.